# How does Salesforce saves the email to the Activity History related list on the appropriate record?

Tags: email, related-list, activityhistory

I am reading through this document - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_my_email_2_sfdc.htm&type=0 - and there does not seem to be much information on **how** Salesforce saves the Email to the Activity History related list. Is this something that is a built in functionality that I can not edit or add to?

Where the arrow is there should be a custom opening line that says

"Hello,
   TEST CUSTOMIZATION TO EMAIL TEMPLATE 1
   Your account is past due by.....etc"

[image: EmailMessage Object]

Comment: You can't really customize the feature, but perhaps you could simply ask about whatever it is you're trying to do, instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am trying to figure out why my customized email template is not saving properly to the EmailMessage object when I send an email. It's kind of a rabbit hole question so I am trying to narrow down the issue as much as possible.

Comment: I could just say the answer is "because Salesforce doesn't save the customized template" but I would like a more thorough understanding on why and how if possible.

Comment: When you send from Salesforce, or to Salesforce? I guess I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: When I send from Salesforce. I will attach a picture.